# Can regex match all the words outside quotation marks?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, match

I recently typed an essay for my lit class, and my teacher specifically stated a word limit that does not include quotations from the piece. And I thought, why not make a script that calculates that for you? I could, of course, do this the boring way by going though the whole text and ignoring the words inside quotation marks, but I have a feeling that there's a neater way using Regex and `Array.count`. As I know next to nothing about Regex, can someone help me/tell me that it's impossible with Regex?

Tl;dr: use Regex to match all words (or spaces, doesn't matter) that are outside quotation marks from a text, and count the items in the resulting array.

Comment: Are there any quotation marks to your text besides the quotations?

Comment: Can quote be escaped or unbalanced?

Comment: @Cratylus no, all text inside " and ' is quotations.

Comment: @anubhava by unbalanced, do you mean unclosed?

Comment: @Bluefire Yes that's right.

Comment: Why don't you write a language parser, like the ones they use for C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy enough using PCRE (or Perl of course):

```
".*?"(*SKIP)(?!)|(?<!\w)'.*?'(?!\w)(*SKIP)(?!)|[\w']+
```

Use the `g` modifier, and `s` if you want to handle multiline quotes.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zC5vK5/2)

Here's the `x` version for readability:

```
  ".*?"              (*SKIP)(?!)
| (?<!\w)'.*?'(?!\w) (*SKIP)(?!)
| [\w]+
```

The first part will match everything inside `"` or `'` quotes and will discard it (`(*SKIP)(?!)`). The second part will match all words (I've included `'` as being part of a word in this example). The `'` character will be counted as a quote boundary only at start/end of words, to let you use things like *isn't* for instance.

Possible modifications:

- To count the text *isn't* as two words, replace `[\w']+` with `\w+`.
- To count text like *mother-in-law* as one word instead of 3, replace `[\w']+` with `[-\w']+`.

You get the point ;)

And here's a full Perl script that uses this regex:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$_ = do { local $/; <> };
print scalar (() = /".*?"(*SKIP)(?!)|(?<!\w)'.*?'(?!\w)(*SKIP)(?!)|[\w']+/gs), "\n";
```

Execute it passing in a file or STDIN containing the text you want to count the words in, and it will output the word count on STDOUT.

Comment: @Bluefire Damn, yes, I'll take care of this in a minute

Comment: Nope, ignore me. Just realised that if 's are taken into account, so will apostrophes.

Comment: @Bluefire Here you go, the second version is much better (it counts *isn't* as a word). If you want to count *isn't* as two words, replace `[\w']+` with `\w+`.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the requirements, could use [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick)

```
"[^"]*"|(\w+)
```

And count the matches of the first [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

`\w+` matches one or more word characters.

See [test at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/dE0qA1/1)

---

Also skip single quoted strings:

```
"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|(\w+)
```

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dE0qA1/3)

Answer (score 2):

A general solution would be pretty tough, since some works will have multi-paragraph quotes, where the first paragraph doesn't close the quote, but the second paragraph opens with a quotation mark.  So matching quote marks document-wide would be hard.

On the other hand, you could maybe go paragraph-by-paragraph, and accumulate a non-quote word count for each paragraph.  There would still be pathalogical cases that could break this (like a paragraph which includes a list of punctuation symbols, including a quotation mark), of course.

In Perl, assuming a getWordCount sub exists somewhere, and assuming you've somehow split your document into an array of paragraphs called @paragraphs, this might look like:

```
my $wordCount = 0;
foreach my $paragraph (@paragraphs) {
    $paragraph =~ s/\".*?\"/g; # remove all quotation marks which have a matching quotation mark
    $paragraph =~ s/\".*$/g; # remove quotation marks which go to the end of the paragraph
    $wordCount += getWordCount($paragraph);
}
print "There are $wordCount words outside of quotations, maybe!";
```

Answer (score 1):

It would work better this way:

Total Number of characters - Sum(characters inside quotes)

You can use this regex to find all "Quoted" strings: \"[^"]*\"