# Regex match all the words outside quotation marks?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, match

Is it possible to match text outside quotation marks by using standard regex parser?
I have seen this answer, but it is done by using PCRE:

[Can regex match all the words outside quotation marks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003778/can-regex-match-all-the-words-outside-quotation-marks/26004005#26004005)

This is not a pure solution because of using PERL. I know that it also can be solved by using programming language, but the idea is to use pure regex parser.

I have made something like this, but this is not working correctly

```
[^'"]*(?=(?:(['"])+(.*?\1))|([^'"]*$))
```

Thank you in advance.

**UPD1**:The idea is to match any kind of text outside quotation marks, the solution must not depend on the input.

Comment: I don't believe there's a single regex that would work for *all* the languages. There will be at least one platform that doesn't support a particular feature.

Comment: __Warning:__ don't use a regex to write a parser for a programming language unless you know _exactly_ what you are doing. Common pitfalls: (1) `"` inside a code comment mistaken for the start of a string literal. (2) `/*` or `//` inside a string literal mistaken for the start of a code comment. (3) `\"` inside a string literal mistaken for the end of the string literal. (4) Failure to recognize tokens inside the placeholders of an [interpolated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
(?:[^"](?=(?:[^"]*?(?:["][^"]*?["][^"]*?)+$)|(?:[^"]*?$)))*|(^[^"]*["][^"]*$)
```

http://regex101.com/r/pI8xA4/2

it will not work very well if we have an odd number of quotes - In this case, it will skip the first quote.
But it is the best solution for me for now.

Answer (score 10):

```
<yourtext>(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Yes you can do it in using positive lookahead.But this assumes you have balanced `"` and there is no stray `"` lying somewhere.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/29

Comment: Can you briefly explain this solution?
What if I want to escape `\"` instead of `"`? Thanks.

Comment: @SamKahChiin it says after `text` there can be groups of `"` <>`"` ahead of it and then there should be no single `"` ahead of those groups till end.So after the text after we have captured all groups of `"`<>`"` , if there is a single `"` left, its a fail

Comment: Why I can't capture `{"` with this ? 

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla what is the expected output

Comment: @vks not really, I wanted to find every match of `{"` outside of double quotes, specifically for dealing with json.

Answer (score 3):

This pattern will capture words outside double quotes

```
"[^"]+"|(\S+)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/58)

or this pattern to capture sentences outside double quotes, you would have to trim extra spaces

```
"[^"]+"|([^"]+)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/59)