# Regex with SKIP for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following regex:

['[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\b[_A-Za-z]\w*\b(?![(']).](https://www.regex101.com/r/FtwAkx/1)

and it works fine as expected (select variables from expression). But when I try to use it in .NET:

```
private string regex = @"'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\b[_A-Za-z]\w*\b(?![('])";
private string _expression = @"12+x1+455+'ggg+4+rrr+tt'+3"

var matches = Regex.Matches(_expression, regex);
```

it does not find anything. I suppose, it's specific to use SKIP in Regex of .NET class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(*SKIP)(*F)` are [PCRE specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/5527985) verbs.

Alternatively to only match outside single quotes [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for an even (balanced) `'`...`'` amount.

```
\b[_A-Za-z]\w*\b(?![('])(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

[See demo at regexstorm](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b_A-Za-z%5d%5cw*%5cb%28%3f!%5b%28%27%5d%29%28%3f%3d%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%29*%5b%5e%27%5d*%24%29&i=12%2bx1%2b455%2b%27ggg%2b4%2brrr%2btt%27%2b3)

There are quite some similar answers available already: [@vks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609791/5527985), [@MarkusQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/632552/5527985)

Comment: I am sorry, but this regex will slow down your program. It is *not* a good solution, and - more - it is not a good workaround either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is just an empty statement. To use this regex on input similar to the samples length won't cause any issues at all (: Of course if the input is large there will be limits.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET and most other flavors, match and *capture* what you need and only match what you do not need:

```
'[^']*'|\b([_A-Za-z]\w*)\b(?![('])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27%7c%5cb%28%5b_A-Za-z%5d%5cw*%29%5cb%28%3f!%5b%28%27%5d%29&i=12%2bx1%2b455%2b%27ggg%2b4%2brrr%2btt%27%2b3)

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/Zyfsaf):

```
var regex = @"'[^']*'|\b([_A-Za-z]\w*)\b(?![('])";
var _expression = @"12+x1+455+'ggg+4+rrr+tt'+3";
var matches = Regex.Matches(_expression, regex)
       .Cast<Match>()
       .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
       .ToList();
```

Alternatively, use [PCRE.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCRE.NET).

Comment: How to exclude 'ggg+4+rrr+tt' from result?

Comment: Have you seen the demo? It is all there. `.Groups[1].Value` holds what you need.

Comment: I don't need 'ggg+4+rrr+tt' in result at all :)

Comment: The *result* is what you get from what regex fetches. You need specific part of text that you *capture*. Else, explain what you are doing. Right now, that sounds as an XY problem.

Comment: compare please https://www.regex101.com/r/GekTga/1 and https://www.regex101.com/r/FtwAkx/1 :) Do you see a difference? '...' included to result in first and excluded in second:)

Comment: I do not care about what regex testers say, the main point is what you get with both regex and *code*. Do you see http://ideone.com/Zyfsaf showing only `x1`? **There is no SKIP-FAIL equivalent in .NET regex flavor**. That is why I suggested using [PCRE.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCRE.NET). You may use ugly workarounds like `\b([_A-Za-z]\w*)\b(?![('])(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)` but I do not guarantee this won't cause catastrophic backtracking one day.