# How to split on a character only if it's outside of quotes in golang?

Tags: regex, go, parsing

I need to split a chunk of text on the `+` symbol, but only when it's outside of single quotes.  The text will look something like:

```
Some.data:'some+value'+some.more.data:9+yet.more.data:'rock+roll'
```

which should become a slice of three values:

- Some.data:'some+value'
- some.more.data:9
- yet.more.data:'rock+roll'

I've [found similar questions that do it using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609745/regex-match-all-the-words-outside-quotation-marks), but that requires look ahead which the golang regex engine doesn't have.

I also took a crack at creating my own regex without lookahead:

```
'.*?'(\+)|[^']*(\+)
```

But that seems to fall apart on the third item where it splits on the `+` in `'rock+roll'`.

I've thought about potentially doing a string split on `+` and then validating each slice to make sure it's not a partial expression and then stitching the pieces back together if it is, but it will be fairly involved and i'd like to avoid it if possible.

At the moment I think the best solution would be to identify text that is inside of quotes (which I *can* easily do with regex), either URL encode that text or do something else with the plus sign, split the text and then URL decode the expression to get the `+` sign inside of quotes back, but i'm wondering if there is a better way.

Does anyone know of a way to split on a `+` sign that is outside of quotes using regex *without* lookahead?  Can anyone think of a simpler solution than my URL encoding/decoding method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain code can be easier:

```
func split(s string) []string {
    var result []string
    inquote := false
    i := 0
    for j, c := range s {
        if c == '\'' {
            inquote = !inquote
        } else if c == '+' && !inquote {
            result = append(result, s[i:j])
            i = j +1
        }
    }
    return append(result, s[i:])
}
```

Comment: Daddy likes....

Comment: @AbeMiessler Be careful with escaped quotes.  A value of `Some.data:'Couer d\\'Alene'` could prove problematic.

Comment: @gopher - I already updated the function in my local implementation to handle escaping, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Slightly old question, but you might consider using [go-andiamo/splitter](https://github.com/go-andiamo/splitter)

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-andiamo/splitter"
)

func main() {
    plusSplitter := splitter.MustCreateSplitter('+', splitter.SingleQuotes)

    s := "Some.data:'some+value'+some.more.data:9+yet.more.data:'rock+roll'"

    if parts, err := plusSplitter.Split(s); err == nil {
        for _, part := range parts {
            println(part)
        }
    } else {
        println(err.Error())
    }
}
```

[try on go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/qvuF_aNGyDi)

Disclosure: I am the author of go-andiamo/splitter